# Babel config to SWC

Tags: babel-loader, swc

Now I have such babel config on the project and I really want to rewrite this case under swc. Would anyone be able to help with this

```
 module.exports = {
      sourceMaps: true,
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            exclude: ['transform-async-to-generator', 'transform-regenerator'],
          },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        [
          '@babel/preset-typescript',
          {
            isTSX: true,
            allExtensions: true,
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
        ['module:fast-async', { spec: true }],
        [
          '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
          {
            asyncGenerators: true,
            generators: true,
            async: false,
          },
        ],
      ],
    };
```

Now I have written such a config, but part of the application has stopped working with similar errors: [MobX] Cannot decorate undefined property: 'description'

```
test: /\.(tsx|ts|jsx|js)$/,
      loader: 'swc-loader',
      options: {
        jsc: {
          keepClassNames: true,
          parser: {
            syntax: 'typescript',
            decorators: true,
            tsx: true,
            dynamicImport: true,
            preserveAllComments: false
          },
          transform: {
            legacyDecorator: true,
            decoratorMetadata: true
          },
          loose: false
        },
      },
```